# ListView inside a BottomSheet

Tags: android, listview, bottom-sheet

I am writing an application that retrieves place information from a server and displays it on a ListView inside a BottomSheet, much like the behavior of the Google Maps app. However, I am facing two issues:

1) When the BottomSheet is dismissed, performing another search doesn't display the ListView at first - only when I'm interacting with the screen (placing a marker somewhere else or touching the BottomSheet) does the list show up.

2) When the BottomSheet is expanded, I can't collapse it because the ListView is the one intercepting the touch events. If it weren't, there wouldn't be a way to scroll through the list. Setting `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` on the ListView doesn't work, either: The ListView is able to scroll up, but scrolling down collapses the sheet.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

**BottomSheet in the activity layout file**

```html
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                />
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/circular_indicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**BottomSheet code**

```
    View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
    mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            switch (newState) {
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                    mFAB.show();
                    adapter.clear();

                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    });
```

**AsyncTask in the activity**

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(500);

        mFAB.hide();
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<City> cities) {
        super.onPostExecute(cities);

        for (City c : cities) {
            adapter.add(c);
        }

        mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.